# Changing Collection view flow layout

Tags: ios, collectionview, flowlayout

I'm having this issue with switching flow layouts, in the view debugger it changes to the flow layout that I want, however in the simulator and on my phone it's a jumbled mess. I've been looking everywhere for an answer or what the problem is and I can't find a solution. ![left side is what im trying to accomplished and how the view debugger looks, right is the simulator][1]

here is the code for the collectionview and the flow layouts -

```
(void)setupCollectionView
{
    CGRect mainscreen = [[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds];

    self.originalLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc]init];
    self.otherLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc]init];


    self.collectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc]initWithFrame:mainscreen collectionViewLayout:self.originalLayout];
    self.collectionView.delegate = self;
    self.collectionView.dataSource = self;
    [self.collectionView registerClass:[MyCollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    [self.collectionView setPagingEnabled:YES];

    [self.originalLayout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal];
    [self.originalLayout setMinimumInteritemSpacing:0.0f];
    [self.originalLayout setMinimumLineSpacing:0.0f];
    self.originalLayout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(self.collectionView.frame.size.width, self.collectionView.frame.size.height);

    [self.otherLayout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal];
    [self.otherLayout setMinimumInteritemSpacing:10.0f];
    [self.otherLayout setMinimumLineSpacing:10.0f];
    self.otherLayout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2, self.view.frame.size.height/2);

    [self.view addSubview:self.collectionView];
}

-(void)changeLayout
{
    if (self.topBar.hidden == NO) {
        self.topBar.hidden = YES;
        self.bottomBar.hidden = YES;
    }
    if (self.swapCollectionViewLayout == NO) {
        self.swapCollectionViewLayout = YES;

        [self.collectionView setPagingEnabled:NO];

        [self.collectionView setCollectionViewLayout:self.otherLayout animated:YES];

        [self.collectionView reloadData];
    }
    else
    {
        [self.collectionView setCollectionViewLayout:self.originalLayout animated:YES];
        self.collectionView.pagingEnabled = YES;
        self.swapCollectionViewLayout = NO;
        [self.collectionView reloadData];
    }
```

Here is a link to a photo of the issue 
https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=909831825747700&l=340de9351b